# Series split column with condition

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas series contains `year` values. They're not formatted consistently. For example,

```
df['year']

1994-1996
circa 1990
1995-1998
circa 2010
```

I'd like to grab the `year` from the `string`.

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str)
df['Year'] = df['Year'].str[:4]
```

This doesn't work for rows with `circa`.

I'd like handle the rows with `circa` and grab only the year if it exists.

```
df['Year'] 

1994
1990
1995
2010
```

Comment: Could you add the data as a pandas df that we can run? maybe just `grep` for digits{,4} and/or remove all instances of circa from the string? Also why choose 1994 and not 1996?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['Year_Only']=df['Year'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})')[:4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.extract` then convert as `pd.Int16Dtype`:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(pd.Int16Dtype())
print(df)

# Output
   Year
0  1994
1  1990
2  1995
3  2010
```